# Safari can’t open the page “localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback?

Tags: safari, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

My application in localhost work. But in production, when subscribe by facebook, it display this error:

> Safari can’t open the page “localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback?

Comment: you need to use the correct hostname instead of "localhost" i guess

Answer (score 0):

Browser security policies are preventing a remote page from accessing a HTTP server running on localhost.

To correct this problem use your server's public hostname (FQDN) and make sure your application is reachable from outside.

Comment: that is to say, i change ip: process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0' by my ip server ?

Answer (score 0):

How i add public hostname !

```
 'use strict';
    /*eslint no-process-env:0*/

    import path from 'path';
    import _ from 'lodash';

    /*function requiredProcessEnv(name) {
      if(!process.env[name]) {
        throw new Error('You must set the ' + name + ' environment variable');
      }
      return process.env[name];
    }*/

    // All configurations will extend these options
    // ============================================
    var all = {
      env: process.env.NODE_ENV,

      // Root path of server
      root: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/../../..`),

      // Browser-sync port
      browserSyncPort: process.env.BROWSER_SYNC_PORT || 8080,

      // Server port
      port: process.env.PORT || 8080,

      // Server IP
      ip: process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0',

      // Should we populate the DB with sample data?
      seedDB: false,

      // Secret for session, you will want to change this and make it an environment variable
      secrets: {
        session: 'azertysoft.com'
      },

      // MongoDB connection options
      mongo: {
        options: {
          db: {
            safe: true
          }
        }
      },


      facebook: {
        clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID || '167..57940',
        clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET || '748efa9d9a...a8a0364',
        callbackURL: (process.env.domain || '') + '/auth/facebook/callback'
    /*
        callbackURL: 'ppollit.azertysoft.com/auth/facebook/callback'
    */
      },

      twitter: {
        clientID: process.env.TWITTER_ID || 'dDp8Hd...HV0t0W2c',
        clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_SECRET || 'aFA7...z9AwfbJqXZ61GqkP',
        callbackURL: (process.env.domain || '') + '/auth/twitter/callback'
      },

  google: {
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_ID || '964...472168-jk3eu7aohfik6njj46u1...pps.googleusercontent.com',
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET || 'Void0kcp237F7Skt9Jpfg6_C',
    callbackURL: (process.env.DOMAIN || '') + '/auth/google/callback',
    client_id: 'AIzaSyBu...NHSl-XAxbBbkls'
  }
};

// Export the config object based on the NODE_ENV
// ==============================================
module.exports = _.merge(
  all,
  require('./shared'),
  require(`./${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js`) || {});

    enter code here
```